# Symfony 4 Custom Event Dispatcher not Working

Tags: symfony, events, symfony4

I have followed the Symfony 4.3 docs to create a custom event, dispatch it, and listen for it. Tracing the execution of my controller, it looks like the event dispatcher does not find any subscribers, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My event class is very basic:

```
namespace App\Event;

use Symfony\Contracts\EventDispatcher\Event;

class TestEvent extends Event
{
    public const NAME = 'test.event';

    protected $data;

    public function __construct(string $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function getData(): string
    {
        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

My controller instantiates and dispatches the event:

```
class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    private $eventDispatcher;

    public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/event", name="event_test")
     */
    public function eventTest()
    {
        $event = new TestEvent('Event string');
        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch($event);

        return $this->render('Test/TestEvent.html.twig', [
            'title' => 'Test Event',
            ]);
    }
}
```

I set up a subscriber to listen for the event and log. To make sure the subscriber works, I also subscribed to a Kernel event (that works):

```
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use App\Event\TestEvent;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class TestSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            TestEvent::NAME => [['onTestEvent', 20]],
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => 'onKernelRequest',
        ];
    }

    public function onTestEvent(TestEvent $event)
    {
        $this->logger->info('Subscriber says: Found test event');
        $this->logger->info('Subscriber says: Test event posted this data {data}', [
            'data' => $event->getData(),
        ]);
    }

    public function onKernelRequest()
    {
        $this->logger->info('Got Kernel Request');
    }
}
```

When I visit the /event URL, I see the expected output, and the logs show the Kernel request, but they don't show the test.event log.

Per the docs, I ran

```
php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher test.event
```

at the console and got

## Registered Listeners for "test.event" Event

---

Order   Callable                                       Priority

---

#1      App\EventSubscriber\TestSubscriber::onTestEvent()   20

---

That tells me the subscriber is registered, but for some reason it is not being called. Any help would be fantastic!

(BTW, I tried with an event listener as well, and got the same results.)

Thanks!

Comment: Why does console show notify instead of onTestEvent?

Comment: @Cerad Good catch, I changed the function name from "notify" to "onTestEvent" as I was composing this question. The console output I posted was old. I've updated the output.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In symfony 4.3 if you dispatch event like this `$this->eventDispatcher->dispatch($event);` dispather use method `get_class($event)` as event name, so in your subscriber you need change

```
TestEvent::NAME => [['onTestEvent', 20]],
```

to

```
TestEvent::class=> [['onTestEvent', 20]],
```

For listener use this:

```
App\Event\TestListener:
        tags:
            - { 'name': 'kernel.event_listener', 'event': 'App\Event\TestEvent', 'method': 'onTestEvent' }
```

Comment: Fascinating! That works like a charm, but to see the registered listener in the console I have to call it by class name (php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher "App\Event\TestEvent").

Comment: $dispatcher->dispatch($event, TestEvent::NAME); will make your original code work as well.

Comment: Yes, but this is old way and soon be deprecated

Comment: Not exactly.  The old way had you pass $eventName as the first argument.  That approach has now been depreciated in 4.3.  Passing $eventName as the second argument is now supported and will continue to be so.  Notice that the various kernel events still use names like kernel.request even in 4.3.  I don't disagree that you should use class name instead of event name but both approaches are fully supported and will continue to be so.

Comment: For the record, dispatching with the event name in the second argument and subscribing to the name, as Cerad said, worked in my test as did dispatching without the name and subscribing to the class as @IhorKostrov said.

Comment: I tried your solution with symfony 5 but it not working, event is not fire, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66134109/symfony-5-eventsubscriber-auto-wiring