# symfony 5 - event not being dispatched

Tags: php, autowired, symfony5, symfony-eventdispatcher

I use an event subscriber to handle some actions when my order form is submitted.

Problem my event is not being dispached but symfony is able to find him because he tells me that my OrderEvent::ORDER_CREATE is orphan.

I excpected that execution was stopped with `die('Hello you from subscriber');` but it's not.

Controller

```php
public function commanderPanierAction(Request $request, SelectionWeb $selectionWeb, TableLumineuse $tableLumineuse, EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher)
{
    // DO PREVIOUS STUFF

    $Order = new Order();
    $OrderForm = $this->createForm(OrderForm::class, $Order);
        
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
      $OrderForm->handleRequest($request);

      if ($OrderForm->isSubmitted() && $OrderForm->isValid()) {
          // OrderForm is valid proceed
          $eventDispatcher->dispatch(
              new OrderEvent($Order),
              OrderEvent::ORDER_CREATE
          );
      }
   }
```

OrderEvent

```php
<?php

namespace App\Event;

use App\Entity\Order;
use Symfony\Contracts\EventDispatcher\Event;

class OrderEvent extends Event
{
    public const ORDER_CREATE = 'order.created';

    protected $order;

    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order= $order;
    }

    public function getOrder(): Order
    {
        return $this->order;
    }
}
```

OrderSubscriber

```php
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use App\Event\CommandeWebEvent;
use App\Service\SelectionWeb\SelectionWeb;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;


class OrderSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $entityManager;

    private $selectionWeb;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, SelectionWeb $selectionWeb)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->selectionWeb = $selectionWeb;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            OrderEvent::ORDER_CREATE => [
                // The higher the number, the earlier the method is called.
                ['processOrder', 10],
                ['notifyOrder', -10]
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function processOrder(OrderEvent $event)
    {
        // TODO
        die('Hello you from subscriber');
    }

    public function notifyOrder(OrderEvent $event)
    {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The only workaround found (thx to @nikserg) is to inject subscriber into controller action (subscriber has dependencies) then register my subscriber as service in `services.yaml` finaly use `$eventDispatcher->addSubscriber($subscriber);` before `$eventDispatcher->dispatch(new OrderEvent($Order),OrderEvent::ORDER_CREATE);`

It seems all that stuff is really complex for a task as simple as that

**EDIT2**

I found an another way I'm able to execute my subscriber without usage of `$eventDispatcher->addSubscriber($subscriber);` and only with `$eventDispatcher->dispatch(new OrderEvent($Order));` only if I configure my subscriber as service in `services.yaml` but why symfony does need this information in services.yaml ? Thought that everything in src/ is avaible to be used as service..

```yaml
# makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
# this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

# If I add those It works
App\EventSubscriber\OrderSubscriber:
    autowire: true
```

**EDIT3**

My OrderSubscriber is loaded into container so why I should set it explicitly to being execute ? I can't figure out what's going on

```sh
php bin/console debug:container
---------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
Service ID                               Class name
---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
App\EventSubscriber\OrderSuscriber App\EventSubscriber\OrderSuscriber
```

**EDIT 4**

If I set my `OrderSubscriber` explicitly there is two instances of it into container.
Why symfony execute one set explicitly and not the one set with `resource: '../src/*'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I want to thank you all for your time and let me apologize my problem was due to a typo I wrote `OrderSuscriber` instead of `OrderSubscriber` that's why there was 2 services into my container and why defined service explicitly was working.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony will autowire your subscriber as service, if you will require it as argument in action:

```
public function commanderPanierAction(Request $request, SelectionWeb $selectionWeb, TableLumineuse $tableLumineuse, OrderSubscriber $orderSubscriber)
```

Of course, if your subscriber is registered properly.

But let me advice you not to create subscribers as objects manually. The main good thing about subscribers is that you **know nothing** about them, when you fire event. There could be dozens of subscribers to this event, and all of them will proceed your event. That will keep your code nice and lower cohesion.

It's in docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber

Comment: So the correct way is to require subscriber as argument in action ?

Comment: If you definitely want to create an instance of your subscriber, then yes.
But I strongly recommend you not to touch subscriber in place, where you fire event.

Comment: I read the doc and followed it, how I'm supposed to use addSubscriber from dispatcher without instanciate object ? I don't want definitively create an instance I'm just looking for the best way to use events. If you have some advices to do what I want and keep my code clean it will be appreciate.

Comment: You don't need to add add subscriber manually. It will catch your event, as long as event defined in getSubscribedEvents() inside subscriber's class. It's all magically automated.

Comment: Unless I does'nt undestand something I commented `$dispatcher->addSubscriber($subscriber);` and my event is not firing..

Comment: As I see in your code, you use OrderEvent::COMMANDE_WEB_CREATE instead of OrderEvent::ORDER_CREATE in getSubscribedEvents(). In getSubscribedEvents must be same string, as when you call $dispatcher->dispatch().

Comment: Right it's a mistake when I wrote the post, but my code is clean and same event is used

Comment: docs says `To register a subscriber with the dispatcher, use the addSubscriber() method` https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html#using-event-subscribers

Comment: I noticed that my event is not fire and he is marked as Orphaned Events in profiler..

Comment: And I noticed that getSubscribedEvents() is not executed too